# Php get seasons select

Tags: php, date

I have a seasons array in PHP. Season is autumn now.

```
[seasons] => Array
(
    [0] => Summer
    [1] => Autumn
    [2] => Winter
    [3] => Spring
)
```

I want to sort by following.

```
[seasons] => Array
(
    [0] => Autumn 2017
    [1] => Winter 2017
    [2] => Spring 2018
    [3] => Summer 2018
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Where is your code?

Comment: I am asking because I can't write the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$seasons = ['summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'spring'];
$current_season = 'autumn';
$current_season_key = array_search($current_season, $seasons);
$seasons_temp = array_splice($seasons, $current_season_key);
$new_seasons = array_merge($seasons_temp, $seasons);
var_dump($new_seasons);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "autumn"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "winter"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "spring"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "summer"
}
```

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: I know that, if set to current season date ("n"), it is works. Also,  this package usefull. https://github.com/jaybizzle/php-seasons/